# get Access token in foursquare

Tags: foursquare, access-token, clientid

I want to get access token foursquare like this link `https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless' and this is code

```
https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token
?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
&code=CODE
```

I don't understand what `YOUR_CLIENT_ID`,`YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET` and `YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI` are. Can you explain and show some examples ? Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Before you get started, you should create an app on Foursquare. This will give you a client ID and client secret which are needed for using the API. The documentation in this guide is meant to give a high-level conceptual overview of the Foursquare platform, help you grok its different parts and capabilities, and get started using the API’s most popular features."

https://developer.foursquare.com/start

Comment: Is there any way one can create two app with a single developer account?
Or can have two ClientID for a single app?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the link: https://foursquare.com/developers/apps

Click the option: "Create a new app". Enter the name of the app and a valid url from where your app can be downloaded. These two fields are mandatory. You can provide the details for other fields also. If you don't have a download link, you can create a folder in dropbox (google drive, onedrive) and provide that link. Create your app and you will get your private CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET.